# Merging cells within the same table in SAS or Proc Sql

Tags: sql, merge, null, sas

I have a table with a customer column followed by multiple columns (relating to shops) and a flag to indicate if they have visited this shop, if they haven’t, the cell is null. The shops are listed in order of importance, with Shop1 being highest, the shop2, shop3 and so on…. The flag to say if a customer has visited that particular shop is a number relating to the shop number. So for example, if a customer hasn't visited shop1 this will be blank, but if they have visited shop2, this cell will be '2'.

I need to merge the columns together, to create a table which for each customer has the top 4 shops they have visited, so for example the entry for a customer could read first column '2', second column '5',third column '7', fourth column '8' as they haven't  visited shops numbers 1,3,4 or 6. Could someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: if would be better if you show us an example of your data and what do you expect and have you tried

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.  Take the input data (what I assume you mean), perform a transpose, filter the missing (null) values, and transpose again.

```
data input;
input customer $ shop01 shop02 shop03 shop04;
datalines;
Bill 1 2 . .
Ted  . 2 3 .
;

proc sort data=input;
by customer;
run;

proc transpose data=input out=temp(where=(col1 ^= .) drop=_name_);
by customer;
run;

proc transpose data=temp out=output(drop=_name_);
by customer;
run;
```

This gives me:

```
Bill 1 2
Ted  2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Given how your data is laid out, you could use the `smallest` function with a variable list to return the first smallest non-missing value in your shop variables, the second smallest, and so on.

```
data test(drop=shop01-shop08);
  set input;
  first  = smallest(1,of shop01-shop08);
  second = smallest(2,of shop01-shop08);
  third  = smallest(3,of shop01-shop08);
  fourth = smallest(4,of shop01-shop08);
run;
```